# White supremacists -- is there any indication of ideology or are they just a criminal gang?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

The gang that Walt has in employed *Breaking Bad* season 5 show a strange moral code -- leaving him 10 million dollars is extremely unusual behavior for criminals but might be consistent with actual white supremacists who respect Walt as a fellow white person. Do we have any indication that the gang really has any ideology or are they basically criminals with swastika tattoos?

Comment: Usually people don't get swastikas tattoos unless they ARE some sort of white supremacists.

Comment: @Luciano: The prison gangs in the usa like the aryan nation certainly don't have black/jewish/etc. members but that does not mean that they really have much of a political agenda -- they are gangs first, dedicated to making money and controlling prisons.

Comment: @Luciano: But the gang might not be specifically targeted at white supremacy. I'm not saying it definitely isn't either, but there's a difference between a white supremacist gang and a gang of white supremacists. Similarly, an all male gang wouldn't inherently have to be focused on gender identity either.

Comment: @Flater true. Since there was no clear indication it was a white supremacist gang we can assume it was a gang with some white supremacists. Perhaps that's enough for some of them to follow some of the moral code (perhaps not the whole ideology).

Comment: @Flater: I love your "difference between... white supremacists" As I mentioned, the Aryan Brotherhood is a gang of criminals first, they make no bones about this while other white supremacist groups really care about issues like segregation, etc. that the Brotherhood might agree with but it is hardly part their raison d'etre.  Arguable, AB would be looked down upon by some white supremacist groups because they are criminals. Uncle Jack is probably somewhere in the middle with some sort of moral code, at least he would say so.

Comment: The behavior is due to Todd, who spoke to his uncle (Jack, the gang head). From the script "*Jack and Todd confer privately. We can’t hear what they’re saying -- but it appears that Todd is advocating for Mr. White’s life*", then Jack said: "*Pull one of those barrels off the truck. Load it in the Chrysler.*", then to Walt: "*My nephew here, he respects you. He would never forgive me if things... went another way*"

Comment: We know that they have a deeply-held ideological opposition to the outlawing of smoking on commercial flights.